# Can not execute middleware if using a exception handler?

Tags: clojure, cors, compojure, compojure-api

[wrap-cors](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors) does not return access control headers when there is a bad request against my api endpoint. I believe this is because I am using a exception handler which might be blocking the middleware from running. I want to know how I can still execute the middleware for this route and append the cors headers to the response of bad requests.

exception handler

```
(defn- bad-request-handler
  "Handles bad requests."
  [f]

  (f
    (ring/response {:status "bad request"})))
```

app

```
(def app
  (api
    {:exceptions {:handlers
                          {::ex/request-validation (bad-request-handler response/bad-request)}}}

    (POST "/" [] :body [item {(schema/required-key :item) schema/Bool}]
             :middleware [#(wrap-cors % :access-control-allow-origin [#".*"]
                                      :access-control-allow-methods [:post])]

             :responses {200 {:description "ok"}
                         400 {:description "bad request"}} item)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to append my own headers rather than using r0man/ring-cors.
I can determine the contents of the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` by retrieving the `:request-method` value from the request. 
However, this makes the assumption that the bad request handler will only ever be called by valid routes.

```
(defn- append-cors
  "Allow requests from all origins"
  [methods]

  {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "*"
   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" methods})


(defn- bad-request-handler
  "Handles bad requests."
  [f]

  (fn [^Exception e data request]
    (->
      (f request)
      (update-in [:headers] merge (->
                                    (request :request-method)
                                    (name)
                                    (clojure.string/upper-case)
                                    (append-cors)))
      (assoc :body {:status "bad request"}))))
```

I'm still not really sure why the cors headers are only added when the request is allowed.